# netBeans and ucanacces sql exception only calling db from code

Tags: java, database, sqlexception, netbeans-8, ucanaccess

Well, this is a little odd, I installed succesfully the driver, and in the services tab, my database tables show correctly, but when I call the driver from code I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\sample.mdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at sampleProject.TestDBConnection.main(TestDBConnection.java:16)
```

Here's my code:

```
package sample;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class TestDBConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
           // Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            System.out.println("sample.mdb");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\sample.mdb");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tableSample");
            while(rs.next())
             System.out.println(rs.getString("RunnersSample") );
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Anyone knows why I cant acces from code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you're probably using a different  ucanaccess.jar (likely built from the sources) from that in the current distribution:
in this jar there must be the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file.
Also, the JDK must be a JDK at least Java 6.

EDIT:
The exception is unambiguous: the driver isn't registered.
One time, before java 6, you had to invoke Class.forName in order to register the driver, so that a static block initializer of the driver class was invoked in turn, registering the driver.
Starting from  java 6, you  need no more to do that, because someone else does it for you. But the driver has to specify by contract  the name of the driver class in the content of the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver (unizip the ucanaccess.jar to ensure that this file exists and its content is correct). And in the NetBeans services, if a driver weren't compliant, NetBeans would likely call Class.forName for compatibility with old drivers. Notice that the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver had been already put  inside ucanaccess 2.0.4.1(but this is such a old version!) so maybe you're using a different jar from that in the distribution.
In particular, if there isn't a  META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file, it means your ucanaccess.jar isn't that of the sourceforge distribution.

EDIT 2: Obviously, YOU ALWAYS MUST IMPORT the ucanaccess.jar and the four dependencies jars(hsqldb, jackcess, commons-lang, and commons-logging) into your NetBeans  project libraries, even if you configured ucanaccess as service.
This was an assumption of my considerations above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jamadei. I have JDK 8, that shouldn't be a problem, but I don't understand the other part of the answer, I installed the jar of the 2.0.4.1 version of the UCanAccess tool,  followed all the steps in the website to integrate this on netbeans, it works on the service tab, and I don't know what I need to do from your answer, to make it work in the code, can you explain me a little more? Sorry, I'm a noob on netBeans.Thanks!

Comment: Hope what I wrote above may help you.

Comment: Sorry, but no... I'm lost here, with other databases, and older versions of java was easier to connect, I don't know how to fix this, and I'm starting to hate acces databases >.< Thanks anyway, i'll keep trying!

Comment: So, basing on your feedback I suspect to have done a wrong assumption:
see the edit2 above.

Comment: Thanks again, i'll try and i'll tell you if works
EDIT: I use an aold version because it was the one recommended on ucanacces website, i'll try to do as you said, and tell you the results. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, the meta inf is in there, but how can I import those files to my project? (I mean hsqldb, jackcess, commons-lang, and commons-logging)

Comment: Well, the  meta data is there, now my problem is how to import the jar and the libraries, for the last, i tried via the menu: Tools > Libraries, but it doesn-t work, and i don-t know how to import the jar. Any Idea? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, as usual you just have to right click on the libraries folder of your project, choose add jar/folder item and then select the five required jars.

Comment: Thanks, i'll reply as soon as I try it

Answer (score 0):

Try using a double slash (//) before the path and single slashes (/) for the path like this:

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/sample.mdb");
```